# How Does Initalizing a Javascript Modal Work in Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I see other answers, but I still do not understand what initializing javascript means and how I am supposed to add the javascript part to my HTML page? If I want to include this modal in my HTML page:

```
 <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am told I need to initialize it first using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

If I add this (the javascript portion) to the end of the `material.js`, it has no effect. If I add it in the HTML page and wrap it around using  like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
          $('.modal').modal();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular JavaScript to initialize it instead of the jQuery that you're using:

```
M.Modal.init(document.getElementById('modal1'));
```

You can put that code in a `<script>` tag or include a .js file, but make sure you do so below the modal `<div>` and the Materialize sources.

The full code could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Modal test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
   <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    <script>
         M.Modal.init(document.getElementById('modal1'));
    </script>
</html>
```